# I can't get my removeDuplicate method to work?

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

My program reads an input file, which is a `txt file` that contains duplicates of first and last names. I am unsure why the `removeDuplicate` method isn't removing the duplicates and instead giving me an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        String fName;
        String lName;

        System.out.println("What is the input file?");

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = kb.next();

        File list = new File(fileName);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(list);

        System.out.println("What is the output file?");

        String outFileName = kb.next();

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(outFileName);

        while (in.hasNext()) {

            fName = in.next();

            lName = in.next();

            names.add(fName + " " + lName);
            removeDuplicates(names);
            display(names);


            outFile.println(fName + " " + lName);

        }
        outFile.close();

    }
}
```

Here's the methods outside of my Public main

```
public class StudentList {

    public static void display(ArrayList<String> n) {
        // step through all positions of the ArrayList n and display the values
        // at each positoin
        for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i = i + 1) {
            System.out.println(n.get(i));
        }
    }


    public static int find(ArrayList<String> names, int i) {

        String s = names.get(i);
        for (i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.size(); j = j + 1) {
                if (s.equals(names.get(j))) {

                    return j;

                }
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> names) {

        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
            while (find(names, i) > 0) {
                names.remove(find(names, i));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Set<String>` instead of an `List<String>`? This way duplicates get removed automagically

Comment: Do you really want to print out the whole list of names every time you add a new one? Also, if you want to use this method, you only need to remove duplicates once after you've added everything. At the moment you're comparing every possible pair when there is only one possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's comments about using a `Set` are correct. This is the data structure you should use. However, the problem with your code is in your `find()` method. You pass in an `int i` and set `String s = names.get(i)` you then peform a nested for loop but never change your string s.

Try this:

```
public static int find(ArrayList<String> names) {


    for (i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
        String s = names.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < names.size(); j = j + 1) {
            if (s.equals(names.get(j))) {

                return j;

            }
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Notice that you set s equal to the ith element inside your for loop. You no longer need the parameter I in your method. However, this may change your code. If you want to simply try to find everytime something occurs you would want this:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> find(String name, ArrayList<String> names) {
  ArrayList<Integer> duplicateIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    if (names.get(i).equals(name)) {
      duplicateIndices.add(new Integer(i));
    }
  }
  return duplicatIndices;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to simplify your code and not need to programmatically remove any duplicate you could use a `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Basically either:

- `Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>(); // unordered, doesn't keep duplicates`
- `Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); // keeps insertion order, doesn't keep duplicates`
- `Set<String> names = new TreeSet<String>(); // ordered by lexicographic order, doesn't keep duplicates`

You could then dispose of both `find` and `removeDuplicates`.

Note that in either case duplicates would be case-sensitive - but that's what your code does at the moment.